# Isolated Points [Confusion Regarding Size of Neighborhood]

Tags: general-topology

I'm learning (general?) topology and am having trouble understanding the definition for Isolated Points. The definition from Wikipedia says:

"A point $x$ of a topological space X is called an isolated point of a subset $S$ of $X$ if $x$ belongs to $S$ and there exists in $X$ a neighborhood of $x$ not containing other points of $S$"

Now, my main confusion is with "...a neighborhood of $x$ not containing other points of $S$". How exactly large is this neighborhood? For example, for the set $S$ = ${0} \cup$ { $1$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\cdots$} why is $0$ not an isolated point?

Comment: The neighbourhood can be as small as it pleases. In your example set, _every_ neighbourhood of $0$ (in the standard topology) contains all but finitely many points of $S$, so $0$ is not isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, a set $N$ is a nbhd of $0$ if and only if there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq N$. No matter how small $\epsilon$ is, we can always find an integer $n>\frac1\epsilon$, so that $\frac1n<\epsilon$, and then we have

$$\frac1n\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap S\;.$$

Thus, every nbhd of $0$ contains other points of $S$.

This is not the case with the other points of $S$. Consider the point $\frac15$, for instance. $N\subseteq\Bbb R$ is a nbhd of $\frac15$ if and only there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $$\left(\frac15-\epsilon,\frac15+\epsilon\right)\subseteq N\;.$$ Let $\epsilon=\frac15-\frac16=\frac1{30}$; since $\frac14-\frac15=\frac1{20}>\frac1{30}$, it’s clear that

$$\left(\frac15-\epsilon,\frac15+\epsilon\right)\cap S=\left(\frac15-\frac1{30},\frac15+\frac1{30}\right)\cap S=\left\{\frac15\right\}\;,$$

so $\frac15$ is an isolated point of $S$. A similar calculation can be carried out for any other element of $S\setminus\{0\}$ to show that $0$ is the only non-isolated point of $S$.

However, all of this depends on the fact that we’re talking about the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, the one whose open sets are the unions of open intervals. There are many other topologies on $\Bbb R$, and in some of them $0$ **is** an isolated point of the set $S$. The simplest of these is the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) on $\Bbb R$, in which **every** subset of $\Bbb R$ is open. In this topology every point of $S$ is an isolated point of $S$: if $x\in S$, then no matter what $x$ and $S$ are, $\{x\}$ is a nbhd of $x$ that contains no other point of $S$.

Comment: This was a lot more in depth then I thought it would be. Why do you allow epsilon to be $\frac{1}{30}$? Where did $\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}$ come from?

Comment: @Ozera: Any positive $\epsilon\le\frac1{30}$ would have served equally well: I just need an $\epsilon$ small enough so that $\left(\frac15-\epsilon,\frac15+\epsilon\right)\cap S=\left\{\frac15\right\}$. $\frac14-\frac15$ is the distance from $\frac15$ to $\frac14$, its other neighbor in $S$ besides $\frac16$; any $\epsilon$ small enough for $\left(\frac15-\epsilon,\frac15+\epsilon\right)$ to exclude $\frac16$ (and all smaller members of $S$ will automatically be small enough to exclude $\frac14$ (and all larger members of $S$).

Comment: I still don't understand. Why does epsilon have to be $\leq \frac{1}{30}$ ? Why $\frac{1}{30}$ in the first place? Why are you saying $ = {\frac{1}{4}}\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}$? I don't know what is going on now. Agh..

Comment: @Ozera: $\frac13=\frac15-\frac16$ is the distance from $\frac15$ to the nearest other member of $S$. If I want an $\epsilon$-interval around $\frac15$ that excludes all of the other points of $S$, I have to make $\epsilon$ small enough for the interval to exclude $\frac16$. And since $\frac16$ **is** the nearest neighbor to $\frac15$ in $S$, any $\epsilon$ small enough to exclude $\frac16$ automatically excludes all the rest of $S$.

Comment: @Ozera: You’re welcome!